# values within 2 percentiles in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 2 vectors of length 200, say A and B; then I find every second percentile of the array `A` using `A1=prctile(A, [1:2:100],1);` so that `A1` is an array of length 50. Now I want to find the average of the elements of A that fall within each two elements of `A1`( ie. average of elements of A between 2nd and 4th percentile) and also average the corresponding elements of B . I also want to get values of B corresponding to A, like if the elements of A within 2nd and 4th percentile are `[2,8,19]` which may be the 16th, 22nd and 112th element in the array A of length 200, then I also need average of the 16th 22nd and 112th elements of the vector B...

Comment: This question is identical to your previous question, just a little better explained. Instead of creating a new one 1) Improve your existing if you think it can be explained better 2) Do not accept (you can remove the check mark) an answer unless it really answers your question. The third important point is joining the discussion in the comments, which you already did.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want regular percentiles, can you not just take the assumption that they occur at every `n/50` elements of your data when sorted?

```
[ASort, idxSort] = sort(A);
BSort = A(idxSort);

sub = ceil((1:numel(A))/(numel(A)/50))';

AMeans = accumarry(sub, ASort(:), [], @mean)
BMeans = accumarry(sub, BSort(:), [], @mean)
```

Comment: That would be the right answer for `[0:2:100]` percentiles, not for `[1:2:100]` percentiles. Tried it this way first and ended up with a much more complicated solution. See the dup question.

Comment: @Daniel OP talks about getting the mean value between the 2nd and 4th percentile though so the `[1:2:100]` may have been an error